# How to add new row into the beginning of data frame only if the first value of the column Z contains value of "X"?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of about thousand data frames. All data frames have column Z and the column consists mostly on NA values, but whenever there is an actual value, it has either "VALUE1" or "VALUE2" in it. For example:

```
weight | height | Z
---------------------------
62      100      NA
65      89       NA
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
57      84       NA
```

The first actual value of each data frame in the column Z should always contain a value of "VALUE1" in it, so in the example data frame above everything is as it should be. However, if the data frame would look like this:

```
weight | height | Z
---------------------------
62      100      NA
65      89       NA
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
57      84       NA
```

I would need to add a new row into the beginning of the data frame with "VALUE1" in the Z column and value 0 in the height and weight columns. How could I do this for my list of data frames (with the help of functions such as add_row and filter)..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(Z)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  mutate(across(weight:height, ~ 0)) %>%
  filter(!grepl("VALUE1", Z)) %>%
  mutate(Z = "VALUE1") %>%
  bind_rows(., dat)
#   weight height                             Z
# 1      0      0                        VALUE1
# 2     62    100                          <NA>
# 3     65     89                          <NA>
# 4     59     88 randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
# 5     66     92                          <NA>
# 6     64     90                          <NA>
# 7     64     87 randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
# 8     57     84                          <NA>
```

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(weight = c(62L, 65L, 59L, 66L, 64L, 64L, 57L), height = c(100L, 89L, 88L, 92L, 90L, 87L, 84L), Z = c(NA, NA, "randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext", NA, NA, "randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If `dfs` is your list of dataframes, you can do this:

```
dfs = lapply(dfs, function(x) {
  if(grepl("VALUE2", x[!is.na(x$Z),"Z"][1])) {
    rbind(data.frame(weight=0,height=0,Z="VALUE1"),x)
  } else x
})
```